# How to use Jquery UI in my Custom Function? (Autocomplete)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-plugins

I want to create a function to simplify configuration of jQuery UI AutoComplete. Here is my function code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myAutocomplete = function() {
        var cache = {};
        var dataUrl = args.dataUrl;
        var dataSend = args.dataItem;

        $.autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                if (cache.term == request.term && cache.content) {
                    response(cache.content);
                }
                if (new RegExp(cache.term).test(request.term) && cache.content && cache.content.length < 13) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                    response($.grep(cache.content, function(value) {
                        return matcher.test(value.value)
                    }));
                }
                $.ajax({
                    url: dataUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: dataSend,
                    success: function(data) {
                        cache.term = request.term;
                        cache.content = data;
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
        });
    }
}) (jQuery);
```

but when I'm using this function like:

```
$("input#tag").myAutocomplete({
    dataUrl: "/auto_complete/tag",
    dataSend: { term: request.term, category: $("input#category").val() }
});
```

It's give me an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble, I'm not adept at using jquery. Here's the final working code.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myAutocomplete = function(opt) {
        var cache = {};

        this.autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                if (cache.term == request.term && cache.content) {
                    response(cache.content);
                }
                if (new RegExp(cache.term).test(request.term) && cache.content && cache.content.length < 13) {
                    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
                    response($.grep(cache.content, function(value) {
                        return matcher.test(value.value)
                    }));
                }
                opt.dataSend.term = request.term;
                $.ajax({
                    url: opt.dataUrl,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: opt.dataSend,
                    success: function(data) {
                        cache.term = request.term;
                        cache.content = data;
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
        });
        return this;

    }
}) (jQuery);
```

To use this function just write code like this:

```
$("input#tag").myAutocomplete({
    dataUrl: "/auto_complete/tag",
    dataSend: { category: $("input#category").val() }
});
```

Thanks Jeffery To for sharing with me to solve this problem.. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the error is referring to request.term in

```
$("input#tag").myAutocomplete({
    dataUrl: "/auto_complete/tag",
    dataSend: { term: request.term, category: $("input#category").val() }
});
```